# Shutdown my system in 30 minutes with telinit

Tags: runlevel, telinit

If I want to shutdown my system in 30 minutes with telinit, how could I do it? I know that with shutdown is easier but just for knowing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/at.1.html):

```
at now + 30 minutes <<<'telinit 0'
```

Or use `sleep 30m; telinit 0`.

`telinit` itself cannot do this. You will have to use other tools in combination. `at` and `sleep` both allow you to cancel the operation (with `atrm` for `at` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> for the other).

Comment: darn you @muru :) I took too long :(

Answer (score 5):

```
# telinit 0
```

> Runlevel 0 is halt mode. Telling init to enter runlevel 0 will cause all processes to be killed off, the filesystems unmounted, and the machine to be halted. This is a perfectly acceptable way to bring down the system. On many laptops and modern desktop computers, this will also cause the machine to be turned off. [Source](http://www.slackbook.org/html/essential-sysadmin-shutdown.html)

---

Extra in case someone wonders about rebooting:

```
# telinit 6
```

> Runlevel 6 is reboot mode. All processes will be killed off, the filesystems will be unmounted, and the machine will be rebooted. This is a perfectly acceptable method of rebooting the system. [Source](http://www.slackbook.org/html/essential-sysadmin-shutdown.html)

---

To execute something in the future we have the "at" command. That would be:

```
# at now+30 minutes <<<'telinit 0'
```

or sleep:

```
# sleep 1800 && telinit 0
```

(1800 seconds)

Comment: That's [the second duel](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18776293#18776293) I won today. :P You can use the `telinit` manpage as a source. It lists what `0` and `6` do.

Answer (score -1):

As a suggestion, not addressing to your question directly. Even `at` command is not installed by default and  `sleep` with telinit is a great chioce: If you want to try another tool other than **telinit**, you could try *reboot* with **at**:

```
echo reboot | at now +30 m
```

Comment: This is not addressing to the question since he is asking particularly for using telinit. Moreover, `at` command is not installed by default. he can use `sleep` command instead